# Unity: can't call coroutines through pointer/"Function" class?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

Here's my code:

AIBase.js

```
#pragma strict

var in_action: boolean;
var action: function(): IEnumerator = coroutine;

function Update () {
    if(in_action)
        return;

    in_action = true;
    enter_phase();
}

function enter_phase() {
    Debug.Log("entering action");
    yield action();
    in_action = false;
}

function coroutine () {
    Debug.Log("in coroutine");
    yield WaitForSeconds(1);
}
```

If I comment out the "yield WaitForSeconds(1)" the code works and I see "in coroutine" in the debug log.  However, if I put it in, I can't see it anymore.  For some reason, I can't properly call coroutines through pointers or Function classes in UnityScript (but I can call normal functions).  How can I get the functionality I want?

P.S. I realize I can just write:

```
yield coroutine();
```

but I want to be able to have this AIBase be a base class where the actions are set by the derived classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it!

Here's the new code:

```
#pragma strict

var in_action: boolean;
var action: function(): IEnumerator = coroutine;

function Update () {
    if(in_action)
        return;

    in_action = true;
    enter_phase();
}

function enter_phase() {
    Debug.Log("entering action");
    yield StartCoroutine(action());
    in_action = false;
}

function coroutine () {
    Debug.Log("in coroutine");
    yield WaitForSeconds(1);
}
```

just had to change

```
yield action();
```

to

```
yield StartCoroutine(action());
```

Comment: Accept your own answer so that people know the problem has been solved.